# iOS EKEvent to NSString

Tags: ios, icalendar, ekevent

Is there any API in iOS to get `NSString` representation of `EKEvent` object in [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) format?

Comment: iCal is a nasty format, and even though it is a necessary evil, there is no APIs built into iOS. You cold proably find a third party one with a bit of google searching, though.

Comment: Yeah, I know but have no choice. I also google third-party solutions but with no luck. If somebody know any, please tell me.

Comment: Actually I found some libraries such as [iCal4ObjC](https://github.com/cybergarage/iCal4ObjC) and [libical](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/documentation:featured_projects:libical) but both of it can not fetch `EKEvent` into iCalendar format. These libraries are most likely to create and parse iCalendar files.